# Como eu uso o addObject dentro de um Array?

Tags: array, ios, objective-c

Eu tenho um NSMutableArray *arrayFavoritos

No log consigo ver

```
{
        name1 = 6;
        name2 = "Paolo Rossi\nIt\U00e1lia";
        name3 = "cartaz-1982.jpg";
        photo = "copa8.jpg";
        name4 = 24;
    },
        {
        name1 = 6;
        name2 = "Oleg Salenko\nR\U00fassia";
        name3 = "cartaz-1994.jpg";
        photo = "copa5.jpg";
        name4 = 24;
    },
```

EU preciso transformar essa informação:

```
self.tableItems = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo3.jpg"]];
```

Para que esse *array* seja montado dinamicamente

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você tem uma array de objetos no primeiro código certo? Qual é o valor do objeto que interessa para você compor o tableItems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente, você precisa gerar um vetor de objetos UIImage baseado em um outro vetor que contém dicionários cuja chave relevante é chamada photo. Nesse caso, você pode simplesmente percorrer o vetor original, extrair a string correspondente à chave photo e usá-la para construir um objeto do tipo UIImage, adicionando-o a outro vetor:

```
NSMutableArray photos = [NSMutableArray array];
// arrayFavoritos contém elementos de tipo NSDictionary…
for (NSDictionary *photoData in arrayFavoritos) {
    // …e cada dictionary contém um par chave-valor com chave photo…
    NSString *photoName = photoData[@"photo"]; // nil caso não exista
    if (photoName != nil) {
        // …que é usada para construir um objeto UIImage
        [photos addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:photoName]];
    }
}
self.tableItems = photos;
```

Se você quiser extrair apenas os nomes das fotos, sem construir objetos UIImage, você pode usar [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html):

```
NSArray *photoNames = [arrayFavoritos valueForKey:@"photo"];
```

O vetor photoNames conterá ou strings com o valor de photo para cada elemento de arrayFavoritos, ou `[NSNull null]` para os casos onde não há uma chave chamada photo.